# How to pass a simple List<string> to View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have some thing like that:

```
@model List<string>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}
<h2>Details</h2><div>
<hr />
<dl class="dl-horizontal">

    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayName("Name")
    </dt>

    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ElementAt(0))
    </dd>

    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayName("Document")
    </dt>

    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ElementAt(1))
    </dd>
</dl></div><p>
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id = Model.PrimaryKey */ }) |
@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
```

I know that it is wrong but how i can take 2 elements from LIST?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Do you just want to display the 2 values in the view?

Comment: Yes, from list that i pass to View

Comment: `@foreach(var item in Model) { <p>@item</p> }` will display the 2 values. But what is `@Html.DisplayName("Name")` and `@Html.DisplayName("Document")` for?

Comment: It a name of Values. on View it should display like:
Name: Valuel1
Document: Value2

Comment: You should create a ViewModel then.

Comment: Then your model should not be `List<string>` It needs to be a model with 2 properties, `string Name` and `string Document` and use `@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Name) @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Name)` (ditto for `Document`)

Comment: What about return this as Json? It's easy to handle such list as Json on client. And yes, I'm agree with @StephenMuecke, this could be ViewModel as well.

Comment: Create List<Person>  where Person class has properties Name and Document instead of List<string>

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code (in Controller):

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var sampleList = new List<Tuple<string,string>>()
        {
            new Tuple<string, string>("Amir","Niasari"),
            new Tuple<string, string>("Mehdi","Irani")
        };
        return View(sampleList);
    }
```

And then (In View):

```html
   @model  List<Tuple<string, string>>

@{
foreach (var v in Model)
{
    <h2>
            @v.Item1 , @v.Item2
    </h2>
}
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I know thiw way, but I should have a View that look like Name1: value1, name2: value2 and so on

Comment: Ok, use List<Tuple<string,string>>